# Pylint custom checker rule is unknown in Sonar

Tags: sonarqube, pylint

**Target**: use custom pylint rules with SonarQube UI

I created a custom rule for pylint for python selenium webdriver. To check if XPATH locator is used.

```
#webdriver_locator_checker.py
from pylint.interfaces import IRawChecker
from pylint.checkers import BaseChecker

XPATH_LOCATORS = [
    b'XPATH',
    b'xpath'
]


class WebdriverLocatorChecker(BaseChecker):
    """Checks if XPATH locator is used."""
    __implements__ = IRawChecker

    name = 'webdriver-xpath-locator'
    msgs = {
        'WD001': (
            'Locator strategy by xpath is not recommended',
            'xpath-locator-not-recommended',
            'Xpath locators are not recommended, use css locators instead or use class name, id or name if possible.'
        ),
    }
    options = ()

    def process_module(self, node):
        with node.stream() as stream:
            for (lineno, line) in enumerate(stream):
                for locator in XPATH_LOCATORS:
                    if locator in line:
                        self.add_message('xpath-locator-not-recommended', line=lineno + 1)
                        break

def register(linter):
    """required method to auto register this checker"""
    linter.register_checker(WebdriverLocatorChecker(linter))
```

In root directory I added `.pylintrc` file with (to use custom checker):

```
#.pylintrc
load-plugins=webdriver_locator_checker
```

then I linted my files to get a pylint report:
(pylint-checkers - dir with webdriver_locator_checker.py)

```
PYTHONPATH=./pylint-checkers/ pylint ./path/to/locators.py | tee ./pylint.out
```

report file was created correctly with desired rule detection:

```
#pylint.out
path/to/locators.py:31: [WD001(xpath-locator-not-recommended), ] Locator strategy by xpath is not recommended
```

In the project I set up a sonar config file with (to run sonar-scanner):

```
#sonar-project.properties
sonar.python.pylint.reportPath=pylint.out
```

Then I ran sonar-scanner for SonarQube:

```
sonar-scanner   -Dsonar.projectKey=Project1 -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000   -Dsonar.login=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

but the terminal result contains (you need at least 1 pylint rule in a sonar profile to make it working with pylint report):

```
WARN: Pylint rule 'WD001' is unknown in Sonar
```

And this WD001 detection is not visible in SonarQube UI.

**Question**: How to make this rule visible in SonarQube Analysis? (WD001 is custom id)

I use SonarQube local docker SonarQube server 7.9.1

SonarQube Scanner 4.0.0.1744

python 3.6.8

pylint 2.4.2

Answer (score 0):

possible with issue json description and assign report file to sonar. variable
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/generic-issue/

Answer (score 0):

Pylint issues can be imported only if their pylint id is known by the SonarQube python analyzer. This is a limitation of the way pylint is currently integrated with SonarQube. That will be addressed [when pylint issues are imported as external issues into SonarQube](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/MMF-1778). In the meantime, you have to rely on workarounds such as the one you found.